# Repeat column values in existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table with the following structure:

```
Rownumber ID     Type             Category Value
1         100   1-Purchase Order  Address  Cedar Rd
2                                 City     Beachwood
3                                 State    Ohio
4                                 Zip      44122
5         200   1-Purchase Order  Address  Rockside Rd
6                                 City     Independence
7                                 State    Ohio
8                                 Zip      44131
```

I would like to be able to pivot the table to move the Address, City, State and Zip values into columns. But for that to happen I guess I need the ID and Type to be populated for every record.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you

I added the rownumber field and thought about using LAG and LEAD but that did not work.

```
Desired Output
Rownumber  ID       Type            Category     Value
1          100   1-Purchase Order   Address     Cedar Rd
2          100   1-Purchase Order   City     Beachwood
3          100   1-Purchase Order   State    Ohio
4          100   1-Purchase Order   Zip      44122
5          200   1-Purchase Order   Address  Rockside Rd   
6          200   1-Purchase Order   City     Independence
7          200   1-Purchase Order   State    Ohio
8          200   1-Purchase Order   Zip      44131
```

And then eventually

```
Rownumber  ID   Type              Address      City        State  Zip
1         100  1-Purchase Order  Cedar Rd      Beachwood   Ohio   44122
2         200   1-Purchase Order Rockside Rd  Independence Ohio   44122
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for formatting.

Comment: How can your table look like the first image instead of the second?  Why would you make ID and Type NULL for all hose rows?  Probably learning proper database design should be the first thing you do.

Comment: The second zip code in the desired result should be 44131

Comment: Eric - This is an incoming data source in a flat file that I need to import.

Comment: Gen - you are correct, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can assign the `id` using a cumulative max and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id)) as rownumber,
       new_id as id,
       max(type) as type,
       max(case when category = 'Address' then value end) as address,
       max(case when category = 'City' then value end) as city,
       max(case when category = 'State' then value end) as state,
       max(case when category = 'Zip' then value end) as zip
from (select t.*,
             coalesce(id, max(id) over (order by rownumber)) as new_id
      from t
     ) t
group by new_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad408e2801b27f9e5e8d795b1f1f54fa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but when I run this, it nulls out the different value fields.
Before:

Comment: Gordon - when i run the coalesce(id, max(id) over (order by rownumber)) as new_id, it does not populate the id for me across all the rows when I run it locally. Would you know why?

Comment: Check out what happens when you add more rows to the DB Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0db9eb069acba7bf85d19e31ddc4c80e

Comment: @irshansyed . . . It works fine if `rownumber` is defined as in your question -- unique and defining the ordering of the rows.  I've changed the db<>fiddle link to illustrate this.

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the rownumber. But for some reason the new_id refuses to populate across the null rows for me when I run the code. I thought the nulls are some unprintable characters and have been trying to replace them but no luck so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Gordon - I finally figured out why it wasn't working. I had line feeds, carriage returns and blanks in the id column and I had to convert it to an int. But now that it is working, I saw in another set of data that the id is not always coming through sorted. So this doesn't appear to work when that happens. I have been trying to see what I can change to accommodate for that but haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @irshansyed . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question for your new problem.  This question appears to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` statement like this to get intended result:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT RowNumber, ID, Type FROM <Your Table Name>) source
PIVOT
(
    MIN (Value)
    FOR Category in 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'
) AS pvt
```

For more information see `PIVOT` documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017